# unable to install postgresql on SLES 10

Tags: postgresql, installation, sles

i am trying to install postgresql-server on a Suse 10 (SLES10 SP2) 64 bit machine with no luck.
I followed the link on the postgres website to the place where they maintain the build for SUSE:

http://software.opensuse.org/package/postgresql-server?search_term=postgresql-server

When i try to install the rpm package i downloaded it complains about missing dependant libs:

```
# rpm -Uvh postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 3dbdc284
error: Failed dependencies:
    postgresql = 9.0 is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    libldap-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    libpq.so.5()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    libssl.so.1.0.0()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64
```

Now when i try to install on of the dependant libs: libc.so.6 by trying to install glibc-32bit-2.15-21.1.x86_64.rpm, it complains about a missing lib  rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) which i can't find on the internet.
The 32 bit version gives the same problem.

Alternately when i try installing using zypper, it complains about a transaction in progress:

```
zypper in postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64.rpm
A ZYpp transaction is already in progress.
```

Also tried:  yast2 --install postgresql-server
but it says:

```
Following packages haven't been found on the medium: postgresql-server
```

Can anyone please help me out? I feel I am hitting dead ends each way I go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with zypper since it should take care of installing the dependencies as needed.  Per your statement:

> Alternately when i try installing using zypper, it complains about a
>   transaction in progress:
>
> zypper in postgresql-server-9.0.7-12.1.x86_64.rpm A ZYpp transaction
>   is already in progress.

Try killing any zypper process(es) you see.  List zypper processes with

```
ps aux | grep -i zypp
```

Then kill each one with

```
kill -9 pid
```

where pid is the process ID.  Then try your zypper install again.  The following simpler command should work:

`zypper install postgresql-server`

Answer (score -1):

The following link can be followed. It worked for me.

https://www.osradar.com/postgresql-opensuse-15/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.